# componentWillReceiveProps is not called on redux props change

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-thunk

My component is straight forward:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';

import * as instanceActions from '../../../store/instances/instancesActions';

class InstanceDetailsPage extends Component {

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        console.log('will receive props');
        if (nextProps.id !== this.props.id){
            this.updateInstanceDetails();
        }
    }

    updateInstanceDetails = () => {
        this.props.actions.loadInstance(this.props.instance);
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <h1>Instance - {this.props.instance.name}</h1>
        );
    }
}

function getInstanceById(instances, instanceId) {
    const instance = instances.filter(instance => instance.id === instanceId);
    if (instance.length) return instance[0];
    return null;
}

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
    const instanceId = ownProps.match.params.id;
    let instance = {id: '', name: ''};
    if (instanceId && state.instances.length > 0) {
        instance = getInstanceById(state.instances, instanceId) || instance;
    }
    return {
        instance,
    };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        actions: bindActionCreators(instanceActions, dispatch)
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(InstanceDetailsPage);
```

My reducer which I'm pretty sure I'm not mutating the state:

```
import * as types from '../actionTypes';
import initialState from '../initialState';

export default function instancesReducer(state = initialState.instances, action) {
    switch (action.type){
        case types.LOAD_INSTANCES_SUCCESS:
            return action.instances.slice(); // I probably don't event need the .slice() here, but just to be sure.
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

I know for sure that the state change which triggers props change because I logged `this.props` on the render method, and the props changed couple of times!
With that, the `componentWillReceiveProps` wasn't called even once.

What can cause that?

Comment: i would guess it has to do with what your mapStateToProps is returning, you should throw some logs in there and make sure you are not returning the same instance over and over. This would then make your component not update because props are not changing. It would be better practice to not perform manipulations in mapStateToProps

Comment: @EricHasselbring at first it's an empty object, and when the instances are loaded, it contains the instance data.

Comment: if you log shouldComponentUpdate and compare (nextProps, nextState) with current, do you see differences?

Comment: It's also never being called. @EricHasselbring

Comment: The lifecycle is as follows: "constructor, will mount, render, did mount" x3

Comment: ahh good point, what if you log, componentWillUnmount.. so there could be a conditional render above it that is unmounting it, in which component updates are not called

Comment: Ok you are right. The lifecycle is: "constructor, will mount, render, did mount, unmount" x3 when the last one doesn't have unmount. Why is it unmounting???? @EricHasselbring

Comment: is the parent doing an iterations over arrays or objects to display it? if the key is changing, then react will think its a new component and unmount it and create a new one

Comment: The page is loaded with react-router, the component is mounted after the instances are loaded so no state change occur. I guess my problem is bigger. Thank you I will take a closer look.

Comment: yeah, check to see what else might be listening to state.instances, you may find a bug there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are a few reasons why componentWillReceiveProps will not be called,

- if its not receiving a new props object from the redux store
- additionally these methods are not called if a component is mounted. So you may see your component update, but it is really just mounting and unmounting. to fix this, look into the parent rendering this component and check to see if it is rendering the component with a different key or if there is some sort of conditional render that may return false and cause react to unmount it.